# How to get file extensions in order to compare them and then put an image of it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file

Here is my code (I'm using rails and slim) but I'm getting an error:

```
- case file

  when File.extname(file) == '.doc'

    = image_tag('filetypes/doc.png', class: 'document-image')

  when File.extname(file) == '.xls'

    = image_tag('filetypes/xls.png', class: 'document-image')

  else

    = image_tag('filetypes/pdf.png', class: 'document-image')

  end
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_when
; @output_buffer.safe_concat(("\n  <when>File...
```

If you can help with this I would appreciate it!! (Or another way to improve it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is that you are using `=` in your `when` statements.

Please know that, `=` is used to `render` something. In your case, you will instead need to use `-` with your `when` statements, so that they can actually be processed.

Therefore, your code will become:

```
- case file
  - when File.extname(file) == '.doc'
    image_tag('filetypes/doc.png', class: 'document-image')
  - when File.extname(file) == '.xls'
    image_tag('filetypes/xls.png', class: 'document-image')
  - else
    image_tag('filetypes/pdf.png', class: 'document-image')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem!! Now I'm getting a different error:
undefined local variable or method `file' for #<#<Class:0x007f0b0886a9d8>:0x007f0ae4834f78>
but I supposed I'm just have to call in some way the 'file' variable in order to make it work.

Comment: Please, open another question with your error and the code you are using, and I will try to help if I can.